# Convergence of $\int_0^{1/2}\frac{1}{x^\alpha \log x}dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

To establish, for which values of real parameter $\alpha$, the integral
$$\int_0^{1/2}\frac{1}{x^\alpha \log x}dx$$
exists finite. For me, this problem is very difficult. Any suggestions please?

Comment: For which values of $\alpha$ can you answer the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your integral is convergent if and only if $\alpha<1$.

By the change of variable
$$
x=e^{-u},\quad u=-\log x,\quad dx=-e^{-u}du,
$$ one obtains
$$
\int_{0}^{1/2} x^{-\alpha}\frac1{\log x} d \, x=-\int_{\ln 2}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{(\alpha-1)u}}{u}du
$$ A potential problem of convergence is as $u \to +\infty$, in which case:

> - if $\alpha -1<0$ then

$$
\frac{e^{(\alpha-1)u}}{u}<e^{(\alpha-1)u}
$$  and the latter function is convergent over $[\ln 2,+\infty)$ giving the *convergence of your initial integral*.

> - if $\alpha -1=0$ then

$$
\int_{0}^{1/2} x^{-\alpha}\frac1{\log x} d \, x=-\int_{\ln 2}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{u}du
$$ giving the *divergence of your initial integral*.

> - if $\alpha -1>0$ then

$$
\frac{e^{(\alpha-1)u}}{u} > \frac1u, \qquad u \to +\infty
$$ giving the *divergence of your initial integral*.